# Minimal time to ride all ski slopes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Suppose we want to know what the minimum time is to ride all ski slopes on a mountain. We know the time it takes to ride a slope, and we know the time it takes to take a ski lift to get from one ski station to another, given that we have to end up where we started.

This screems Minimum-Cost-Flow-Problem to me. Thus my first idea was to construct a directed graph, whose vertices represent the ski stations and the edges represent the slopes and lifts. Let the cost of an edge equal the time it takes to ride that slope/lift. Now I want to find the minimal time it takes to ride every slope (note: not necessarily every lift), but I can't seem to find a way to ensure that we have to ride every slope atleast once.
Is there a chance to do it this way or am I completely wrong with my attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your problem is a lightly disguised version of Traveling Salesman (note that since you have to ski *all* the slopes, for algorithmic purposes the skiing time is irrelevant, all that matters is the time to travel between slopes.)

Comment: I'm not sure if the skiing time is irrelevant, since the ski lifts don't have to start "at the bottom", they can start in the middle of a slope and go up the mountain, "dividing" the slope into two slopes.

Comment: @blst you can account for it by refining the graph...

Comment: Can you explain that more?

Comment: @blst think of a slope as a set of slopes, where the travel time from slope $i$ to slope $i+1$ is $0.$ Each consecutive subsequence of slopes $i, i+1, \dotsc, i+k$ should also be counted as a slope...

Comment: I understood the refining of the graph. With your hint I thought of constructing a digraph, where the vertices represent the slopes, and an edge represents the time to get from one slope to another. Then this problem would be equivalent to the travelling salesman problem, but wouldn't be a lot of fun to calculate, depending on the amount of slopes. I think my Min-Cost-Flow approach is doomed...